# Is it possible to target just a few devices for an Android app?

Tags: android

I built an Android app that must be used with 2 devices only (it's part of a configuration process).

Today, 10K devices are elligible for my app, but I'd like my app to only be available for the 2 targeted devices (that represent thousands of owners).

Is there any way to do it in the AndroidManifest.xml or in the Google Play Store Console?

Example: the app is only for the device "Samsung S20 FE" and not for all the other android devices in the world.

**EDIT**

It looks like it's possible to import a list of devices to exclude. The [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455) says:
[image: instructions from documentation]

I cannot find the "Import manually excluded devices" option in my console?! See below (it's in French):
[image]

Comment: Get the manufacturer name and model details and if the model is different move user to different activity which shows "Device not supported" if the device matches then move user to required home activity

Comment: @AgentP I wouldn't suggest that as when people download the app and see **Device Not Supported** , they would just leave bad rating

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a device compatibility list in the google play console:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question: after reading several times all the paragraphs in the documentation, it seems I have to either manually select the devices to exclude (18K devices with a 500 by 500 selection…), or I can import a list of devices to exclude… However I cannot find the option described in the documentation?! See the update of my question.